# How to write data into an RFID tag using KA-02 RFID Reader/Writer and C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, rfid

Recently, I bought a KA-02 RFID Reader/Writer and after several attempts for writing to its blocks using C#, I was unsuccessful.

First of all, its manual says that for writing a 10-digit Hex UID such as **1234567890** to a tag using this device the following command must be used:

```
serialPort1.WriteLine("1234567890\r\n");
```

Then I used a code block like below to write data to my tag:

```
void writeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort MyCOMPort = new SerialPort();
    MyCOMPort.PortName = "COM4";
    MyCOMPort.BaudRate = 9600;
    MyCOMPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    MyCOMPort.DataBits = 8;             
    MyCOMPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;      
    MyCOMPort.Open();                    
    MyCOMPort.WriteLine("1234567890\r\n");
    MyCOMPort.Close();
}
```

The code seems to work properly and throws no exception but after all nothing is written to the RFID tag. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Remove the Close.  You could be closing the device before the message is sent.  Serial Ports work off of Windows timers and you could be closing the device too soon.  I would first start by using Vendors tools for reading/writing to prove all the connections are working before I start testing with a c# app.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you,  I did that but nothing changed, the result was the same.

Comment: Did it work with vendors software?  Is the baud rate correct?  Is the Com port Correct?  Did device come with own driver?  Are you using vendor drive or standard Microsoft Serial Port Driver?

Comment: The `WriteLine` function already puts a environement new line on the end of the message.  I would recommend using the `Write` function instead.  `serialPort1.Write("1234567890\r\n");` See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.writeline?view=netframework-4.7.2 and look at the Remarks section.

Comment: @jdweng When I connect the device to my PC, it appears under the Ports(COM & LPT) category in device manager with this name: USB-Serial CH340(COM4) and the vendor's software works very well. Also I tried manual installation of the driver and the issue was not solved.

Comment: @Baddack It didn't fix the issue mate. I tested it. Thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: it could be a baud rate issue, make sure the device is set to 9600.  Are you able to take a known terminal program like Putty or HyperTerminal and send it a 1234567890<enter> command?

Comment: I agree with Baddack.

Comment: Did you remove or delay the close() by at least 12ms (12 chars, 9600baud is ~1ms/char) preferablly a bit more e.g. 20ms? As @Baddack suggested did you try a terminal program to do the write?